# Pipeing input to a Java process from Python - Java process does not receive input

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin

I have a Java process that has the following logic:

```
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      while (true) {
        String line;
        LOGGER.info("Waiting to read data");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          LOGGER.info("Got a line!");
          String[] words = line.split(" ");
          for (String word : words) {
              // do something with words
```

I can verify that `stdin` is read from successfully as I can run it via `java -jar myprogram.jar` and manually type in words where it is received once I hit "enter".

My python process looks like so:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    command = ['java', '-jar', 'myprogram.jar']
    p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE)
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Process opened and waiting input\n\n\n")
    for word in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
        try:
            p.stdin.write(word.encode() + b'\n' )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

From what I can tell, my Java program does not complete any of the `readLine` calls as I can see the "Waiting to read data" line but I never see a "Got a line!" line emitted. What is the proper way to wire up stdin between the Python process and Java? From what I can tell this is the correct way to wire these up.

I was expecting the Java process to receive the input from stdin as supplied by the Python process.

Comment: Hi. Sorry if it sounds silly but did you wait for more than 10 seconds before realizing that Python script is unable to send input to your Java program? I tested your Java code with your Python code. They seem to work together fine on my end.